# Добавление записи в MySQL!

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите, не могу занести переменную $browser в БД!
Cуть такова: есть 2 скрипта
1-й отвечает за последний визит на сайте
2-й за браузер с какого заходили

Последний Визит заносится в БД норм, а браузер вообще не заносится!
ПОДСКАЖИТЕ ГДЕ Я ДОПУСТИЛ ОШИБКУ?))

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
//Подкл. к БД!
include_once ("config.php");

$visitCounter = 0; 
if(isset($_COOKIE[ 'SnipCodeVisitCounter' ])){ 
    $visitCounter = $_COOKIE[ 'SnipCodeVisitCounter' ]; 
    $visitCounter ++; 
}

if( isset( $_COOKIE[ 'SnipCodeLastVisit' ] ) ){ 
    $lastVisit = $_COOKIE[ 'SnipCodeLastVisit' ];     
}

setcookie( 'SnipCodeVisitCounter', $visitCounter,  time()+60*60*24*100);  
$date = setcookie( 'SnipCodeLastVisit', date("d.m.Y" )." в ".date("H:i:s"),  time()+60*60*24*100);

if($visitCounter == 0){ 
    echo "Добро пожаловать!"; 
} else { 
echo "Вы были у нас " . $visitCounter.get_end_last_vizit( $visitCounter, array(' раз', ' раза', ' раз') ).".<br> Последний раз ".$lastVisit;

}

function get_end_last_vizit($n, $titles)
 {
     $cases = array(2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);
     return $titles[($n % 100 > 4 && $n % 100 < 20) ? 2 : $cases[min($n % 10, 5)]];
}

echo "<br/>";
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

function getBrowser() {
   $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$agent)) { $browser = 'Internet Explorer'; } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$agent)) { $browser = 'Mozilla Firefox'; } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$agent)) { $browser = 'Google Chrome'; } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$agent)) { $browser = 'Apple Safari'; } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$agent)) { $browser = 'Opera'; } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera Mini/i',$agent)) { $browser = 'Opera Mini'; } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$agent)) { $browser = 'Netscape'; } 
    else { $browser = 'Неизвестно'; }
    echo "Ваш браузер: $browser";

}
getBrowser();

              //Заносим в Базу Данных!
$result_post = mysql_query("INSERT INTO box (vizit,browser) VALUES ('$lastVisit','$browser')",$db);       
?>
```

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Answer (score 1):

Может все-таки надо, чтоб функция **getBrowser()** что-то возвращала, а не выводила на экран? В противном случае - откуда ж возьмет значение переменная **$browser**?

```
function getBrowser() {
    // ваши проверки
    return $browser;
}
$browser = getBrowser();
```

P.S. Можно конечно извращаться с помощью **global**, но это не есть гуд.

Comment: все равно не добавляет!

Comment: @amf1k, во-первых, ошибку какую-то выбивает? Во-вторых, сделайте следующее:

    $query = "INSERT INTO box (vizit,browser) VALUES ('$lastVisit','$browser')";
    echo $query; // убедиться, что данные подставлены правильно
    $result_post = mysql_query($query,$db);

Comment: почему-то $browser пустая?

Comment: все исправил, извините за невнимательность!

Comment: Вы внимательно прочитали мой ответ? [Вот так должно](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hwy-uvg) у вас выглядеть.

Comment: $browser = getBrowser();

function getBrowser() {
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$agent)) { $browser = 'Internet Explorer'; }
elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$agent)) { $browser = 'Mozilla Firefox'; }
elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$agent)) { $browser = 'Google Chrome'; }
elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$agent)) { $browser = 'Opera'; }
elseif(preg_match('/Opera Mini/i',$agent)) { $browser = 'Opera Mini'; }
else { $browser = 'Неизвестно'; }
echo "Ваш браузер: $browser";
return $browser;
}